# Cannot install eclipse adt plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I am trying this for the past two days but don't seem to get a right direction to the solution. I have been trying to install the ADT plugin for eclipse Juno but while doing so though the install new software option in help, and providing the url, it starts calculating the dependencies in downloading for a longer time but doesn't complete the calculation. 
Previously, when i tried downloading any eclipse package, it gave me a weird time remaining for downloading the software packages (2 hrs, 4 hrs, 1 day etc.). I don't know if this is a problem with the eclipse server or some other technical issue.
Please note, this is not the first time i am using eclipse so I have been trying to follow the same methods like i used to do. I also tried doing it on a friend's PC and on a different network as well, but same issue existed.
Please guide me accordingly people. I appreciate it.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try downloading the new Android SDK at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

As I explained in [a post on my blog:](http://www.luisdelarosa.com/2012/11/16/official-android-sdk/)

> It is basically Eclipse 3.8 + Android Developer Tools (ADT) 21, pre-installed in a single downloadable package. Previously, Android programmers had to go through a multi-step process to locate the ADT update site, accept licenses, etc. This should save time for new installs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But it's strange to know that when I tried doing it 2 days back, it gave me problems opening a new project. But doesn't seem to give me now. Anyways, this solution definitely helped me a lot.